# How to don't rerender root app component after every <a href> from menu (with BrowserRouter/Switch)

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, href, i18next

I'm beginner in frontend/React, and I've found problem in my application.
So we have 3 components:

> App (root) -> Application -> Menu

And if I choose tab from Menu it every time rerender App component (I have init function there, and it's reinit after every click something in Menu). How could I change my code, to don't do that (I've tried useMemo in App, but it didn't work, so I think something with my Menu code isn't correct).

App(root):

```
const App = () => {

  i18next.init({(...)});

  return (
    <I18nextProvider i18n={i18next}>
      <OtherProviders>
         <Application />
      </OtherProviders>
    </I18nextProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Application:

```
const Application = () => {
(...logic...)
return (
    <div>
        <div ref={node}>
            <FocusLock disabled={!open}>
                <Burger/>
                <Menu/>
            </FocusLock>
        </div>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/page1">
                    <Comp1/>
                </Route>
                <Route path="/page2"> 
                    <Comp2/>
                </Route>
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Application;
```

Menu:

```
const Menu = () => {
  (...logic...)
  return (
    <StyledMenu>
      <a href="/page1" tabIndex={tabIndex}>
        <span aria-hidden="true">1</span>
        {t('menu.page1')}
      </a>
      <a href="/page2" tabIndex={tabIndex}>
        <span aria-hidden="true">2</span>
        {t('menu.page2')}
      </a>
    </StyledMenu>
  )
}

export default Menu;
```

And after every click on

> <a href ...>

in menu my application reload all app, including  component, so in every click on menu href i18next is reinitializated. What's wrong here, and how to change that behaviour?

EDIT:
You're right. I tried this, but  wasn't in , so additionally I had to change  code to:

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <div ref={node}>
        <FocusLock disabled={!open}>
            <Burger/>
            <Menu/>
        </FocusLock>
    </div>
    <div>
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/page1">
                <Comp1/>
            </Route>
            <Route path="/page2"> 
                <Comp2/>
            </Route>
        </Switch>
    </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

After that everything working correctly.

Comment: use components that are provided by the `react-router-dom` package, instead of the anchor tag `a`, use `Link`

Comment: please do not initialize i18next in the App component.... this will initialize i18next multiple times.... have a look at this guide: https://dev.to/adrai/how-to-properly-internationalize-a-react-application-using-i18next-3hdb

Comment: Thank for additional advice adrai, I felt it wasn't good, but I didn't know how to do this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use <a href... that triggers an html load of a new uri

Instead use something like [Link](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#link) from react-router-dom

`<Link to="/">...</Link`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Link` component from `react-router-dom`

```
import { Link } 'from react-router-dom';

<Link to="/page1">
  <span aria-hidden="true">1</span>
  {t('menu.page1')}
</Link>
```